Automating Extension Interaction in Chromium with Python
I'm currently developing a Python script with the goal of automating the activation of the an extension within a Chromium environment. The script's purpose is to streamline the process of refreshing proxies, launching and activating the extension, and then closing the browser. This would greatly optimize the workflow across my 40+ GoLogin profiles, which I am currently handling manually.
However, I've encountered a challenge: it seems that Pyppeteer is unable to initiate a click on the extension's icon, and simulating keyboard shortcuts isn't triggering the extension either.
I'm reaching out to seek any advice or insights on interacting with a Chrome extension within an automated browser setup like AntiBrowser. Has anyone faced a similar challenge, or can anyone suggest alternative methods for automating extension interactions?
Cheers !
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import connect

async def perform_actions(ws_url):
    try:
        
        browser = await connect(browserWSEndpoint=ws_url)
        pages = await browser.pages()
        page = pages[0]  
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        await page.focus('body')

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        
        await page.keyboard.down('Control')
     
        await page.keyboard.press('S')
       
        await page.keyboard.up('Control')

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        print("Actions performed on the existing browser session.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        await browser.disconnect()

I'm getting the ws URL from the multilogins software.

Maybe try playwright? It is very similar to puppeteer; except I find it more intuitive and easier to understand. It also is a new python library, so it might have a solution for chrome extensions.

In fact, it does have a solution for chrome extensions. Here's a link to the chrome extensions in the docs as well: chrome extensions for playwright.

It seemed to me that Playright can't interact with popup extension, in my case, this would be the solution. I just need one click in the tool bar in fact ...

Can you also post your playwright code in the question? Hmm...did you check every method in the docs? Did you try locating the toolbar as an element and clicking it?

I have no Playright code so far, but i did some reasearch and triggering a popup still isnt available in Playright, nor in Pyppeteer, nor in Selenium hehe that's why it's so tricky to find a solution

Try this page on dialogs. There's something in there about the page.on() method to trigger popups. That might work. If it doesn't, you might need to write your own web scraper that can trigger a popup.
